# Powershell - Exchange O365 - size of listed sharedmailboxes excluding some of another list

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm really new to powershell (and dev) sorry...
I need to list the size of some shared mailboxes on ExchangeO365 but not all of them. This code is from internet

```
#Prepare Output file with headers
Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,MailboxSize,ProhibitSendQuota,ProhibitSendReceiveQuota" -Encoding UTF8 

#gather all shared mailboxes
$objMailboxes = get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,MailboxSize,ProhibitSendQuota,ProhibitSendReceiveQuota


#get mailboxstatistics and Iterate through all mailboxes (but take long time)
Foreach ($objMailbox in $objMailboxes) 
{     
    #Connect to the users mailbox 
    $objMailboxStats = get-mailboxstatistics -Identity ($objMailbox.UserPrincipalName) | Select TotalItemSize

    #Prepare UserPrincipalName variable 
    $strUserPrincipalName = $objMailbox.UserPrincipalName 
    $strDisplayName = $objMailbox.DisplayName 

    #Get the size  
    $ItemSizeString = $objMailboxStats.TotalItemSize.ToString() 
    $strMailboxSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($ItemSizeString.SubString(($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1),($itemSizeString.IndexOf(" bytes") - ($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1))).Replace(",","")/1024/1024) 


    #Get the quotas 
    $ItemSizeString = $objMailbox.ProhibitSendQuota.ToString() 
    $strMailboxProhibitSendQuota = "{0:N2}" -f ($ItemSizeString.SubString(($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1),($itemSizeString.IndexOf(" bytes") - ($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1))).Replace(",","")/1024/1024) 
    $ItemSizeString = $objMailbox.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota.ToString() 
    $strMailboxProhibitSendReceiveQuota = "{0:N2}" -f ($ItemSizeString.SubString(($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1),($itemSizeString.IndexOf(" bytes") - ($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1))).Replace(",","")/1024/1024) 

    #Output result to screen for debuging 
    #write-host "$strDisplayName : $strMailboxSize" 

    #Prepare the user details in CSV format for writing to file 
    $strMailboxDetails = ('"'+$strUserPrincipalName+'","'+$strDisplayName+'","'+$strMailboxSize+'","'+$strMailboxProhibitSendQuota+'","'+$strMailboxProhibitSendReceiveQuota+'"') 

    #Append the data to file 
    Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject $strMailboxDetails -Encoding UTF8 -append 


}
```

and tadaa! i got a csv but i would like to not request mailboxstatistics for some specific shared mailboxes

some new shared mailboxes may be created and i dont want to risk to forgot to add the new one to the cheklist

so i prefere to create a .txt file that will list all unwanted mailboxes so if i forgot to add some new unwanted mailboxes, it wont be dramatic, and i can correct it once a year

```
#here is the list of undesired sharedmailboxes, it contains UserPrincipalName only
$excludeMailboxes = get-content -path c:\temp\listExclusionSharedMailboxes.txt
```

How can i only list statistic usage of sharedmailboxes without those on excludeMailboxes ??
As i said, i'm really noob and if you have a excellent other way to do it, i would be happy to (try to) learn...

thanks to everyone

Comment: Can I just confirm all you're looking for is to only pull share mailboxes from 365 and ignore all other types of mailboxes?

Comment: no. We use shared mailboxes for specific IT department but also for specific users. Those sharedmailboxes got 50Gb maximum quota. Shared mailbox for users are not important. But sharedmailbox used for IT department or some internal application should never be full, in case of missing strategic mails.

The code i found on internet list all sharedmailbox, and loop on every mailbox founded to get-mailboxstatistics but we have a lot of mailbox and it takes a looooong time. We want to do it just on specific shared mailboxes, but it have to stay automatic (when new important sharedbox are created)

Comment: So what Specific departments/users are you trying to get? You can set it up to pull for users so such but you would need to say what exact ones you're looking for

Comment: today we have : 

sharedUsermailbox1@contoso.com
sharedUsermailbox2@contoso.com
sharedDepartmentmailbox1@contoso.com
sharedUsermailbox3@contoso2.com
SharedDepartmentmailbox2@contoso2.com
etc

we only need to list the sharedDepartmentMailboxes

i we use the script as it is, it will loop on every share mailbox (sharedUserMailboxes and SharedDepatmentMailboxes) and do a get-mailboxstatistics that will take too much time because we have a lot of shared mail boxes

Comment: So we made a listExclusionSharedMailboxes.txt and add all SharedUserMailBox principal name on it. 

Could a script compare the total list of existing sharedmailboxes with my .txt file and only loop Get-Mailboxstatistics on mailboxes that arent in the .txt file ?

Comment: `$toBeIncluded = $objMailboxes  | Where-Object {$excludeMailboxes  -notcontains $_.UserPrincipalName}` - then use `$toBeIncluded` instead of `$objMailboxes` in ForEach

Comment: @robdy the best ! it works and i thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. Let me quickly convert it to an answer so you can accept that if you don't mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This answer assumes that your file contains list with email addresses each in separate line.

Let's first try to save list of mailboxes which should be checked to new variable:

```
$toBeIncluded = $objMailboxes | Where-Object {$excludeMailboxes -notcontains $_.UserPrincipalName}
```

To verify that it's been filtered properly you can compare these two values:

```
$objMailboxes.count
$toBeIncluded.count
```

Once you confirm successful filtering you just need to use new variable in your `ForEach`:

```
Foreach ($toBeIncluded in $objMailboxes)
```

That's all!